# Extends entity and repository

Tags: symfony

I want to create some core for my Symfony app.

The composer create-project will be included my core provided by Github repository.

Structrue of project:

```
Symfony-project/
├─ app/
├─ src/
│  └─ AppBundle/
│     └─ Entity/
│       └─ Category
│     └─ Repository/
│       └─ CategoryRepository
├─ tests/
├─ var/
├─ vendor/
│  └─ core/
│       └─ src/
│           └─ bundles/
│               └─ Entity/
│                   └─ Category
│               └─ Repository/
│                   └─ CategoryRepository   
└─ web/
```

I want extends vendor Entity and Repository by src/AppBundle Classes.

I used annotations inside Entity.

How did solve this problem?

I think about extend class by base category and mark is as final:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Vendor\Namespace\Category as BaseCategory;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
final class Category extends BaseCategory
{
```

In next step add some rules inside app/config/config.yml e.g.

```
my_core:
    extended_entities:
        Vendor\Namespace\Category: AppBundle\Entity\Category
```

and use compillerpass to change metadata

About the Repository I think about the same thing as above or maybe register is as service(??)

But I think it's a little bit reckless and I'm looking for some clues how to do it better.

Comment: Your problem is not clear, try to rephrase it.

Comment: Might want to take a look at how the FOSUserBundle handles extending entities.  But to be perfectly honest, this is the sort of question that if you have to ask it then you probably should not be doing it.  All kinds of challenges await you.